# How to stop macro from being triggered if cell change more than 3 times?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a selection change which will trigger macroA and macroB. Macro A and B is two individual condition which relate to each other. The problem i faced is when both of the two condition in Macro A and B satisfy each other and it will create non ending loop which keep changing the cell value when selection is made.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rowtarget As Integer


For rowtarget = 1 To 20

If Target.Row = rowtarget Then

    If Target.Column = 3 Then

        Call MacroA
        Call MacroB
        Call MacroA         

    End If

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Is there any code that can stop this non ending loop and at the same time create messagebox? I already search everywhere but found nothing. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent additional events from occurring by using Application.EnableEvents = False. Bracket your calls with setting it False, then back to True.

```
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call MacroA
        Call MacroB
        Call MacroA         
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
```

Comment: I need to stop and at the same time I need to create a message box when this happen. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is it possible to check for the conditions without making any changes? You could do that first, and use MSGBOX to display the message.